# streams to strings: merging multiple files into a single string

Tags: java, file-io

I've got two text files that I want to grab as a stream and convert to a string. Ultimately, I want the two separate files to merge.

So far, I've got

```
     //get the input stream of the files. 

    InputStream is =
            cts.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/files/myfile.txt");


     // convert the stream to string

    System.out.println(cts.convertStreamToString(is));
```

getResourceAsStream doesn't take multiple strings as arguments. So what do I need to do? Separately convert them and merge together?

Can anyone show me a simple way to do that?

Comment: String concatenation is one of the *basic* features of java. `String merged = string1 + string2`

Comment: Thanks @johan. do I need a separate InputStream for each file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you want to concatenate streams. You can use a [SequenceInputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/SequenceInputStream.html) to create a single stream from multiple streams. Then read the data from this single stream and use it as you need.

Here's an example:

```
String encoding = "UTF-8"; /* You need to know the right character encoding. */
InputStream s1 = ..., s2 = ..., s3 = ...;
Enumeration<InputStream> streams = 
  Collections.enumeration(Arrays.asList(s1, s2, s3));
Reader r = new InputStreamReader(new SequenceInputStream(streams), encoding);
char[] buf = new char[2048];
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
while (true) {
  int n = r.read(buf);
  if (n < 0)
    break;
  str.append(buf, 0, n);
}
r.close();
String contents = str.toString();
```

Comment: @Erickson awesome! thanks so much. So once I obtain the single stream I can continue with my converting the stream to a string, just as I would before, right?

Comment: Also, for some reason the SequenceInputStream isn't letting me add more than 2 streams. Does it only take two streams at most? I actually need three.

Comment: @LuxuryMode - you can do more than 2, but you have to create an `Enumeration`. I'll update my example.

Comment: @Erickson does your last line there actually convert it to a string? I'm trying to figure out how to print the full string now...

Comment: @LuxuryMode - Yes, it makes a `String` object from the `StringBuilder`. But if you want to print it to `System.out`, you can just pass the `StringBuilder` directly: `System.out.println(str)`

Comment: I guess its just System.out.println(str); at this point? Sorry to keep bugging you, but how do I handle the proper line breaks. Right now the beginning of each new text file is appended to the last letter of the end of the previous file. How can I ensure a new line for the beginning of the next text file?

Comment: Would using BufferedStreams help in this case or could it cause some sort of conflict?

Comment: @Ali - It wouldn't create a conflict, but it wouldn't help, because we are already making bulk reads into a `char[]`.

Comment: @LuxuryMode - Make sure your files end with a new line? Are you going to test the content of each file in case it does end with a new line and you end up with a blank line? If correcting the file contents is not possible, it's probably simplest to get rid of the `SequenceInputStream`, and read each file in a loop, appending a new line at the end of each file.

Comment: I probably wasn't super clear. Right now, im printing out the full string to the console and getting something like this: Doe | John | A | M | Black | 12-5-1983Vance Bob F M 8-3-1980 Brown. So the "Vance" part should start a new line. Not possible with the way we've constructed this so far?

Comment: @LuxuryMode - If it comes out on one line like that, the first file doesn't end with a new line. If at all possible, it should. At the very least, it should be consistent (either it does end with a newline, or it doesn't, not some files one way and some the other). If you know for sure that the files never end with a newline, and you can't change that, the easiest thing would be to read each file individually, appending a newline yourself. Alternatively, you could create something like a `ByteArrayInputStream` that just contains a newline and put it between files in your collection of streams.

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize commons-io which has the ability to read a Stream into a String

http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString%28java.io.InputStream%29

Answer (score 0):

Off hand I can think of a couple ways
Create a StringBuilder, then convert each stream to a string and append to the stringbuilder.

Or, create a writable memorystream and stream each input stream into that memorystream, then convert that to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Create a loop that for each file loads the text into a `StringBuilder`.  Then once each file's data is appended, call toString() on the builder.